# Changing to NVIDIA driver causes Ubuntu 21.04 to freeze on startup

Tags: nvidia, dell, 21.04

I am very new to linux, so bear with me here. I recently installed Ubuntu 21.04 onto my Dell G5 5090 computer. The installation runs perfectly fine. However, after trying to switch to the NVIDIA proprietary drivers (specifically version 460) and rebooting, the installation gets frozen on the Dell logo. I have tried going into tty, using crtl+alt+f1-12, and using the nomodeset fix, but none of them work. PC specs: GPU: GeForce 1660ti, CPU: Intel I5-9400 (6 cores) @4.1GHz, and 8GB ram. My kernel is 5.11.0-18-generic.

Comment: Another piece of information: I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS beforehand, but it had the same exact problem without even installing the nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's fixed, I realized all I had to do was switch to the HDMI port instead of using DP.